# Concrete5 limit Pagination number view

Tags: php, pagination, concrete5

*This is a copy of original question link:* [Concrete5 Pagination - Limit Number of Pages Being Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142855/concrete5-pagination-limit-number-of-pages-being-output/46811565?noredirect=1#comment80570983_46811565)

Hello,

I'm working with Concrete5 and came to a stop. I want to limit number of **page numbers** displayed in Paginations. Currently displayed are: <-, 1, ...,active, *last five page numbers* and ->.

What I'm trying to achive is to limit or set which page numbers I want to display. Like <-, first, active, last and ->

I have a custom theme and so far I found funciton getPages in Pagination.php but changes made here do not affect my pagination display. Post are also displayed on custom tempalte and are type of Page list. My current solutions is with jQuery but I'm sure it's not the right one.

Thanks for your help.

**FOUND THE ANSWER AND POSTED IN ORIGINAL QUESTION**